# Translating STATA syntax into R syntax

Tags: r, stata

I'm having some trouble translating some STATA codes to R codes:

Stata codes:

```
gen joint_gpw = sbud_jpw * q44 if sbud_jpw < 888 & q44 < 888 

gen sbud_gpw_all = sbud_gpw if sbud_gpw < 888 

replace sbud_gpw_all = q31 if sbud_gpw_all ==. & q31 < 888 

replace sbud_gpw_all = joint_gpw if sbud_gpw_all ==. & joint_gpw !=. 

replace sbud_gpw_all = 888 if q16_1 == 0 & sbud_gpw_all ==. 

replace sbud_gpw_all = 888 if (sbud_gpw == 888 & q31 == 888 & sbud_jpw == 888 & q44 == 888) & sbud_gpw_all ==.  

replace sbud_gpw_all = 999 if (sbud_gpw == 999 | q31 == 999 | sbud_jpw == 999 | q44 == 999  | (q44 !=. & sbud_jpw == 888)) & sbud_gpw_all ==.
```

Here is the R code I tried:

```
dat%>%
  dplyr::mutate(joint_gpw = ifelse((sbud_jpw<888 & q44<888),sbud_jpw * q44,NA))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all = ifelse(sbud_gpw < 888,sbud_gpw,NA))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all = ifelse((sbud_gpw_all= NA & q31<888),q31,NA))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all = ifelse((sbud_gpw_all = NA & joint_gpw != NA),joint_gpw,NA))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all) = ifelse((q16_1 = 0 & sbud_gpw_all = NA),888,NA)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all) = ifelse((sbud_gpw = 888 & q31 = 888 & sbud_jpw = 888 & q44 = 888) & sbud_gpw_all = NA,888,NA)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all) = ifelse(((sbud_gpw = 999 | q31 = 999 | sbud_jpw = 999 | q44 = 999  | (q44 != NA & sbud_jpw == 888)) & sbud_gpw_all = NA)),999,NA)
```

Errors that showed up before:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all) = ifelse((q16_1 = 0 & sbud_gpw_all = NA),888,NA)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sbud_gpw_all) = ifelse((sbud_gpw = 888 & q31 = 888 & sbud_jpw = 888 & q44 = 888) & sbud_gpw_all ="
```

I would like to know that if these two set of codes are equivalent? I greatly appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Comment: You need `==` for equality comparison and for NA, `is.na(sbud_gpw_all)`

Comment: The error actually comes from the `)` after `sbud_gpw_all` in the last three lines. Also, you're overwriting `sbud_gpw_all` with every mutate. What you may want to look at is `case_when()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error originates from the closing parenthesis `)` after `sbud_gpw_all` in the last three lines.

Also, despite not the error thrown, you're overwriting `sbud_gpw_all` with every mutate. I don't know Stata and you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example but I have a feeling your code could work like this:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(
    joint_gpw = if_else(sbud_jpw < 888 & q44 < 888, sbud_jpw * q44, NA_real_),
    sbud_gpw_all = case_when(
      sbud_gpw < 888 ~ sbud_gpw,
      q31 < 888 ~ q31,
      !is.na(joint_gpw) ~ joint_gpw,
      q16_1 == 0 ~ 888,
      sbud_gpw == 888 & q31 == 888 & sbud_jpw == 888 & q44 == 888 ~ 888,
      sbud_gpw == 999 | q31 == 999 | sbud_jpw == 999 | q44 == 999 | (!is.na(q44) & sbud_jpw == 888) ~ 999
    )
  )
```

This will first create the column `joint_gpw` using `dplyr::if_else()` if `sbud_jpw < 888 & q44 < 888`. Afterwards, there is a set of conditions (before the `~`) that are checked sequentially. The first that matches the row, provides the value (behind the `~` operator).

Note that, as Sotos pointed out in a comment, `NA`s in R are checked with `is.na(x)`, not with `==`/`!=`, as those will always return `NA`. I omitted the `NA` check for most lines because those are implied in the sequential nature of `case_when()` -- as soon as one condition matches, the later ones are not evaluated anymore. The `NA_real_` is a numeric `NA` value. Using `if_else()` and `case_when()`, you have to be explicit about the data type.